# Задание по русскому языку

Tags: синтаксис, лексика, выбор-слов

Сегодня мне задали вопрос.

Выражение A B C D употребляется после слова «самый» и усиливает его. Ещё в русском языке есть неопределённое местоимение A E F B G и составные союзы B... B..., F...F... и A B... F... . Напишите слово E.

Честно говоря, я вообще не понял суть задания, что за такие выражения, и что надо вписать вместо точек.

Может, кто-нибудь разберется?

Comment: Забавно: только что я тоже задал вопрос о задании из «Высшей пробы». Впрочем, на счет вашего у меня есть идеи )

Comment: Насчёт точек. Это похоже на запись повторяющихся союзов. В таком случае вместо точек ничего вписывать не нужно. Если бы было написано "неопределённые местоимения" (во множественном числе), я бы мог понять задание примерно так: выражение из четырёх слов употребляется после "самый" [например, "самый что ни на есть"]. Дальше, я думаю, понятно (разными буквами обозначены разные слова).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A B C D — что ни на есть (ср.: самый что ни на есть).

A E F B G — что бы то ни было; B... B — ни... ни, F... F — то... то, A B... F... — что ни... то (например: что ни встреча, то пьянка). Таким образом, искомое E = бы.

Суть задания, очевидно, в простой догадке. Точки остаются на месте, вписываются только буквы.

P. S. Вообще, трудно представить, как выполнить остальные задания (их 19; большая часть из них не менее, а иногда более трудна и сложна) за 1 час...

Comment: Это задание из Высшей пробы"?

Comment: @Серж Да. Только что закончился второй тур.

Comment: Я в комментарии выше угадал ответ, но не угадал задание. Ну почти :)

Comment: Да, здесь нужно ни столько знание русского, сколько смекалка.